# Firewalling all incoming traffic with custom rules

Tags: firewall, iptables, ddos

How do you automatically block all incoming traffic by creating custom rule for every connection (in real time) using iptables?

To clarify - the situation is that my linux box is being DDOSed via port 80 and I want to set iptables to catch and block all attacking bots. After couple of hours (and hopefully all the bots used up), I lift the policy and let the legitimate www traffic in.

EDIT: Or if you could suggest any other way of protecting myself against (probably) distributed SYN flood.

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't do it for you.

Dynamically blocking each connection will give you the exact same result as setting a blanket rule to block *all* connections irrespective of their source -- that is, your site will be inaccessible.

If your problem is simply a syn flood, then just turn on syncookies and call it a day. But if it's a true DDoS attack, then you'll need to do a bit more.

Instead, you need to filter your traffic based on some factor present in all the DDoS traffic, but absent in the legitimate traffic, such as the user-agent header, assuming this is web traffic. I've successfully done this using nginx as a reverse proxy, but bear in mind that setting up and managing such a thing is non-trivial and requires an admin who knows his technology. You're not going to resolve it by following instructions on some blog.

If you don't have one, then find one.

Comment: Since I cant diagnose the attack or differentiate malicious packets I thought about catching all the current and malicious traffic and set rules for it. Dropping all incoming traffic would stop working after I lifted the rule - but if I permanently block all current traffic, then lift the auto-adding filter - new and potential legitimate traffic would be allowed with all the bots filtered out (and some unlucky clients:>).
But still, your answer clarified the situation a bit, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't actually work in my experience -- I tried. What I've seen during most DDoS attacks is that hosts are often being constantly added and removed to the attack pool. You can't just block a specific IP set because within an hour there's thousands of new IPs.